# Sending Data from WPF Application to online asp server

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, desktop

I'm working with WPF application that's require to send some data form Desktop  to `asp server` like `Computer Name`,`computer IP`

Any Idea about how this can run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use System.Net.WebClient and send your data to proper url using form or json